# Ben Ish Chai on Tikkun HaYesod

Tags: books-generally, repentance-teshuvah, shovavim-tat

Does anyone where I online I can find a book called תיקון היסוד which was written by the Ben Ish Chai?

Comment: Why is this tagged tikkun? Being one word in a title doesn't warrant the tag. || Do you know anything whatsoever about the nature of this book? If so, it should be edited into the question.

Comment: How do you know he authored such a book?

Comment: Might you perhaps be confusing this with the _tikkun hayesod_ of a different ish; R. Yosef Hayyim Baghdad - the Ben Ish Hai?

Comment: Y have seen this before years.  There is a book of tefilot

Comment: What do you mean by "on tikkun hayesod"? || Why is this tagged 'sexuality'? Do you know something about the contents of the book you are looking for? If so, don't withhold this information from the users.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is a tefila for  the  period  called  SHOVAVYM, shemot vaera,  bo,  beshalach,  Ytro,  mishpatim

[Here](http://www.area.co.il/view.php?siteid=284612&jet=page&menuid=1139562)  is the nussach.